# show JSON object if true

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, razor

I have a JSON file where I am using a foreach loop to loop through that file. Everything is working just fine. At the moment everything is printed in the below code.

```
@{
    bool anyRoomsForChildrenUnder4 = false;
        foreach (var room in Model.Order.OrderLines)
        {
            anyRoomsForChildrenUnder4 = room.NumberChildren0to3 > 0;
            if (anyRoomsForChildrenUnder4) { break; }
        }
}
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
   @{bool prcb = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)Model.Order.Store.JsonDynamic.Da.HotelData.PaymentRequiredForChildrenBreakfast); }
    <tr>
        <th class="small-12 large-6 columns first">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th width="300">
                        <p class="text-left small-text-left">
                            @if (prcb)
                            {
                                <strong>Lunch for children under 3</strong>
                            }
                        </p>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </th>
        <th class="small-12 large-6 columns last">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th width="300">
                        <p class="text-left small-text-left">
                            @if (prcb)
                            {
                                <span>@Model.Order.Store.JsonDynamic.Da.HotelData.PaymentRequiredForChildrenBreakfast</span>
                            }
                        </p>
                    </th>
                    <th class="expander"></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </th>
    </tr>

    <!-- Price for children breakfast-->
    @{bool pfcf = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)Model.Order.Store.JsonDynamic.Da.HotelData.PriceForChildrenBreakfast); }
    <tr>
        <th class="small-12 large-6 columns first">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th width="300">
                        <p class="text-left small-text-left">
                            @if (pfcf)
                            {
                                <strong>OA dummy text for now</strong>
                            }
                        </p>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </th>
        <th class="small-12 large-6 columns last">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th width="300">
                        <p class="text-left small-text-left">
                            @if (pfcf)
                            {
                                <span>@Model.Order.Store.JsonDynamic.Da.HotelData.PriceForChildrenBreakfast</span>
                            }
                        </p>
                    </th>
                    <th class="expander"></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </th>
    </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

But The below code only needs to get printed if the `(anyRoomsForChildrenUnder4)` is *true*. If it is *not true*, the below code should not execute.

> (anyRoomsForChildrenUnder4) > 0 : true -> Print
>
> (anyRoomsForChildrenUnder4) = 0 : false -> Do not print

Does anybody knows how I can do that?

Comment: It sounds like an `if` statement would do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1**

Just store the flag in the `ViewBag` like this:

```
@{
    bool anyRoomsForChildrenUnder4 = false;
    foreach (var room in Model.Order.OrderLines)
    {
        anyRoomsForChildrenUnder4 = room.NumberChildren0to3 > 0;
        if (anyRoomsForChildrenUnder4) { ViewBag.AnyRoomsForChildrenUnder4 = true; }
    }
 }
```

Then you can access it wherever you want like this:

```
@if(ViewBag.AnyRoomsForChildrenUnder4)
{
    // ... print whatever you want
}
```

**Approach 2**

But it is not a good idea to have all that C# code in your view. Do all of that in your controller and pass a model to your view. This model will have everything your view needs and it can be simple.
A better approach is to pass a model to your view from the controller. Have a model like this:

```
public class SomeModel // Give this a better name
{
    public bool AnyRoomsForChildrenUnder4 { get; set; }

    // Put other properties which your view needs
}
```

Then in your controller do this (keep in mind I am making many assumptions here so take this as an example to follow):

```
var model = new SomeModel();
bool anyRoomsForChildrenUnder4 = false;
foreach (var room in Model.Order.OrderLines)
{
    anyRoomsForChildrenUnder4 = room.NumberChildren0to3 > 0;
    if (anyRoomsForChildrenUnder4) { 
        model.AnyRoomsForChildrenUnder4 = true;
        break;
    } 
}
return View(model);
```

Then in your view:

```
@model SomeModel
// ... code
@if (Model.AnyRoomsForChildrenUnder4)
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Hello. I have just updated my question, because I feel that I was a little bit unclear. THe foreach loop is outside the `<html>` tag. Therefore I cannot set the if statement inside the foreach loop.

Comment: @Mimi See my edit. However, you should do what I suggested using the model approach so minimize all the C# code you have in your view.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem for me is that the code is for an email confirmation for a hotel. I cannot models etc. I am forced to have all my code in one document. That is the big problem for me at the moment. So the code in my question, I cannot change it around and so on. I have to make it work from how the code is there.

Comment: It problaly would. But it is not possible for me to do it like you do. Long story.. The code it for emails, and we are running the code through a marketing automation system we have. Therefore I have to have all my code, html, c#, css, razor etc in the same document. 

I have to find a solution where I can print the tables without changing around in the code in my question. But seems like a quite hard task.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't think you get my answer. Just use the first approach

Comment: ah okay. Thank you again. I just tried but getting an error: Is this how the code should look like after your opinion? https://jsfiddle.net/a32zoyjj/2/

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have time to fix errors in your code. You have issues in your code with when to use `@` and when not to use it. Please take some time and read [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/) article. It will help you. Then fix your code.